# Can TFS Merge be any easier?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

Our Solution is big, with many Projects and files. Our branch has about a dozen changes, but the files changed are spread confusingly across the Solution.

Conveniently, TFS can compare two branches and show you just the dozen changes. This is handy to get your head around just what changed and ignore the rest.

However, from that dialog, I do not see a "Merge" option. As a result, in order to merge the dozen changes we still need to spelunk through the Solution.

[image]

Is there an easier way? Surely there must be.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Also, are these real branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would merge an entire branch - the TFS engine is clever enough to only change what has actually changed.